# Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library apc.so

Tags: php, c, caching, apc

I case, I tried to install `APC`.
I run `configure` file it's running normally, but when I try to `make` I get the following errors :

```
/home/ghost/APC-3.1.13/apc_cache.c: In function ‘_apc_cache_user_update’:
/home/ghost/APC-3.1.13/apc_cache.c:818:63: error: ‘IS_CONSTANT_INDEX’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         switch(Z_TYPE_P((*slot)->value->data.user.val) & ~IS_CONSTANT_INDEX
                                                           ^
/home/ghost/APC-3.1.13/apc_cache.c:818:63: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/home/ghost/APC-3.1.13/apc_cache.c:820:22: error: ‘IS_CONSTANT_ARRAY’ undeclared (first use in this function)
             case IS_CONSTANT_ARRAY:
                  ^
Makefile:186: recipe for target 'apc_cache.lo' failed
make: *** [apc_cache.lo] Error 1
```

After that

I run this command `sh -c "echo 'extension=apc.so' >> /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini"`

Check if APC installed

`/opt/lampp/bin/php -r 'echo phpinfo()' | grep apc --color`

Output :

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/apc.so' - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/apc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

How do I fix it ?

Comment: There were build errors, why did you try to load the module? Also you probably need to install it. The code has errors, it doesn't build.

Comment: @iharob Yes, how do I fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compile the extension with a PHP version where `IS_CONSTANT_INDEX` and `IS_CONSTANT_ARRAY` C constants are [no longer available](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/82ecdcdb6352f851e351f70f19b85aff06de0e4b?_pjax=#js-repo-pjax-container). And the APC extension [had not been updated](https://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=APC) since then. The extension seems abandoned, as the [last commit](http://git.php.net/?p=pecl/caching/apc.git;a=commit;h=6a904063fe753299e8c7c5b2c6658b1976a61de2) was in *September 12, 2013*.

So you should whether use another caching extension, or upgrade the APC extension internals. I would rather use [OPcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php) which is bundled with PHP since version 5.5.0.